# How to get the current playing time in vlc Lua extension script

Tags: lua, vlc

I am new writing lua extension for vlc. I have a bare minimal vlc extension that pops a dialog on activating the menu item and logs message to terminal. How to get the current duration of the file which is playing. Looked at this manual https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt but did not help.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the `time` [VLC variable](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__inputvariable.html)

such as:

```
function getTimePassed()
    return vlc.var.get(vlc.object.input(), "time")
end
```

And then use it as:

```
local elapsedDuration = getTimePassed()
local timeAsString = os.date("%H:%M:%S", elapsedDuration)
```

Comment: You can also get the current time using `vlc.var.get(input, "position") * vlc.var.get(input, "length")`. I think `os.date` may be subject to local timezone, better using something custom (see [durationtoostring](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/share/lua/modules/common.lua#L106)). From vlc version > 2 time is in microseconds (was seconds)

Comment: First I tried vlc.player.get_time() in a lua extension, but this doesn't work, so I used this solution and this works, thanks a lot :) frank

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt) you referenced:

```
input.item(): Get the current input item. Input item methods are:
  :duration(): Get item's duration in seconds or negative value if unavailable.
```

So, `input.item():duration()` should give you the duration you are looking for.

Comment: That returns the total duration() in seconds not the elapsed duration().